# not able to create super user in joomla from database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am in a big problem. Earlier my site was on godaddy and I have recently changed the hosting to inmotion hosting. Now the issue is I am not able to login to backend. I tried creating new user from database but it again and again says no user account or username/password doesnot match. The db prefix is 'wq5p3_' but there is no only jos_users table in database, no wq5p3_users table. There is only one user in that table that has id 506.

Does that mean I've not uploaded full database? Or there is only one users table with default prefix? My site is http://hotinri.com.Joomla version is 3.3.
Also Easy Blog, Community extensions are installed on site. Are they creating any problem?

Plus I dont have any previous database backups.
Can anybody guide me through how to create new user?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Comment: Please always give a version with questions like this, 1.5, 1.6-2.5 and 3+ are all different.

Comment: I've added Joomla version in my problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export again your database and try to import tables one by one  or if you have already imported correctly

try insert data user related tables also

```
INSERT INTO `jos_users`
   (`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`)
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2',
    'd2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199', '');
INSERT INTO `jos_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8');
```

password is **secret** change it from admin panel or you can insert new salted password

Comment: There is no 'wq5p3_users' table in database. So where am I supposed to insert this data? There is only 'jos_users' table.

Comment: run queries in your db and try to login with admin2/secret

Comment: I get this :
Warning
Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - sorry, I accidentally changed the prefix in your code before reading the comments below.

Comment: @Lodder no worries rollbacked

Comment: @shalini so have you this user in user table?

Comment: @shalini - In your Joomla Global Configuration, change the prefix from `wq5p3` to `jos`. However you should ensure you imported the full database from your old server which will use the same prefix

Comment: @RakeshSharma yes, i have and I tried running these queries 4 or 5 times but i am getting same response all the time.

Comment: @Lodder - Would that be safe? I mean, that won't create problem in accessing the site. right?

Comment: @Lodder - I changed the prefix in config file and I am now logged in to backend but my site is messed up.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - Yes it was working well before changing prefix.

Comment: Ok lets sum everything up. You site seems to be working and your template is being displayed. This means your users database table is not using the same prefix as the other tables. Go to PhpMyAdmin and ensure ALL tables are using the `wq5p3`, then make sure this value is used in the Global Config. Report back when done

Comment: @shalini may be you have missed some parts of db

Comment: @Lodder - Can I add the list of all database tables here? In comments?

Comment: @shalini "Yes it was working well before changing prefix" then you need to follow "Lodder" last comment

Comment: @shalini - You can add a list if you wish, but add it to your question, not as a comment. Please also following the instructions in my previous comment ;)

Comment: @Lodder - I ran 'SHOW TABLES' query in database and its displaying '
wq5p3_users' also. I am confused. I am not seeing this table in phpmyadmin anywhere and now its listed with 'SHOW TABLES'.

Comment: It might be on the second page. PhpMyAdmin sometimes onlys show a certain amount of tables per page ;)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64316/discussion-on-answer-by-rakesh-sharma-not-able-to-create-super-user-in-joomla-fr).

Comment: Yeah, got it. I am so dumb. I didn't even see that there were other pages also.